# Reshaping pandas DataFrame and saving tuples

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas `DataFrame`, `df.head()`:

```
   userid  followers    experience fixed_date
0   12134      28266  Intermediate 2012-10-15
1   12134      28266  Intermediate 2012-10-15
2   91638        665       Missing 2012-10-15
3  148401        123  Professional 2012-10-15
4    5890       2436  Professional 2012-10-15
```

I'd like to make a new `DataFrame` where the rows are `userid`, the columns are `fixed_date`, and the values are a tuple of `(followers,experience)`.  As you can see, I have duplicate `userid` rows, which is the error I get when I try `df.pivot()`.  But the number of `followers` can change at a later date, so I'd like to capture that for each `userid`.

I can give a little more background about the data.  The rows are currently tweets, so a user can (and often) tweets more than one time in a given day.  Therefore there will also be duplicate `fixed_date` because I disregard exact time of tweet (HH:MM:SS).  In cases where the user tweeted multiple times in a given date, it would be great to group this into the cell value and make an array of tuples.  If this is already asking for too much, it'd be more than okay to just have multiple columns of the same value.  If that's not possible, I can also save the dates to a separate array and enumerate the columns `0..n`.  Just throwing out thoughts.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's not elegant but this will work:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.loc[:, ['followers', 'fixed_date']])  # New frame with just two cols
df2.index = df.userid  # Set the index to user id
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates()  # remove duplicate records
```

Or if you just want the tuples to pass to an array you could do this:

```
df.loc[:, ['userid', 'fixed_date', 'followers']].values
# array([[12134, '2012-10-15', 28266],
   [12134, '2012-10-15', 28266],
   [91638, '2012-10-15', 665],
   [148401, '2012-10-15', 123],
   [5890, '2012-10-15', 2436]], dtype=object)
```

Which you could use to pass as a sparse matrix or convert to a numpy ndarray/matrix.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't accomplish what I described above. I essentially want to convert a DataFrame into a marix, where the rows are `userid`s and the columns are the many dates in `fixed_date`.

Comment: @David, can you be a little more specific with what you want the actual output to look like? I edited my answer to give you an array of 3-tuples that could be used in a sparse matrix, or converted to whatever numpy data type that you want.